# How to emphasize in a listing and keep source columns aligned?

Tags: listings, delimiters, sourcecode, alignment

I use `moredelim` with `*` to highlight some text in my `lstlisting`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}     
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,keepspaces=true}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\rule{9cm}{1pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\bfseries]{*}{*}}] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0     *x10  300.0*
  *x2  300.0*     *x10  400.0*      *x3  300.0*
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is good. Unfortunately, because `*` has zero width, the alignment in the source is all distorted. Is it possible to make `lstlisting` treat `*` as a single space character so the following source generates the same output?

```
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0    *x10  300.0*
 *x2  300.0*   *x10  400.0*    *x3  300.0*
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
```

As a workaround, I have tried to use `literate={'}{\ }2` to replace `'` with 2 spaces. Unfortunately, this appears to break `columns=flexible`.

```
\rule{9cm}{1pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\bfseries]{*}{*}},literate={'}{\ }2] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0   '*x10  300.0*'
'*x2  300.0*' '*x10  400.0*'  '*x3  300.0*'
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\bfseries]{*}{*}},literate={'}{\ }2,columns=fixed] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0   '*x10  300.0*'
'*x2  300.0*' '*x10  400.0*'  '*x3  300.0*'
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

I cannot change the font encoding or font types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hack into the commands for `[i]` type delimeters, `\lst@BeginIDelim` and `\lst@EndIDelim`. It would be nicer to add a new delimeter type, but this would require redefining a lot of internal commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}     
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,keepspaces=true}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@BeginIDelim{\lst@DelimOpen\iffalse{\fi\lst@ProcessSpace\iffalse}{}}
\def\lst@EndIDelim{\lst@DelimClose\iffalse{\fi\lst@ProcessSpace\iffalse}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\rule{9cm}{1pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\bfseries]{*}{*}}] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0    *x10  300.0*
 *x2  300.0*   *x10  400.0*    *x3  300.0*
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\bfseries]{*}{*}},columns=fixed] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0    *x10  300.0*
 *x2  300.0*   *x10  400.0*    *x3  300.0*
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If you do not want the `moredelim` formatting commands to apply to the spaces, you can instead use

```
\def\lst@BeginIDelim{\lst@ProcessSpace\lst@DelimOpen\iffalse{}{}}
\def\lst@EndIDelim{\lst@DelimClose\iffalse{\fi\egroup\lst@ProcessSpace\bgroup\iffalse}}
```

for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}     
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,keepspaces=true}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@BeginIDelim{\lst@ProcessSpace\lst@DelimOpen\iffalse{}{}}
\def\lst@EndIDelim{\lst@DelimClose\iffalse{\fi\egroup\lst@ProcessSpace\bgroup\iffalse}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\rule{9cm}{1pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\underbar]{*}{*}}] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0    *x10  300.0*
 *x2  300.0*   *x10  400.0*    *x3  300.0*
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\underbar]{*}{*}},columns=fixed] 
  id     #1      id     #2      id     #3
  x3  100.0      x3  200.0    *x10  300.0*
 *x2  300.0*   *x10  400.0*    *x3  300.0*
 x10  200.0      x2   50.0      x2  100.0
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

results in
[image]

Comment: A very elegant patch.

Comment: Great solution! A small flaw is that the `moredelim` format applies to `\lst@ProcessSpace` also. With `\bfseries` that doesn't make a difference. With `\underbar` on the other hand the emphasis is one character to wide on each side. Is there a quick fix perhaps?

Comment: @FrankSeifert  I added a quick fix for this problem.